# What is the /etc/subuid file?

Tags: container, uid

Following [docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), I've run a docker with `dockerd --userns-remap=default` which added this line to the `/etc/subuid` file:

```
dockremap:165536:65536
```

I don't understand what it means, please explain.

Comment: The link you mention describes *exactly* what it means.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [subordinate uid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/subuid.5.html) file contains a list of users and the user ids that the user is allowed to impersonate.

In the example:

```
dockremap:165536:65536
```

- `dockremap` is the name of the system user. This can be a UID as well.
- `165536` is the system UID to start the UID mapping at (Which will be UID 0 in the container)
- `65536` is the number of UIDs allowed on top of UID 0 to be mapped. So 165536 + 65536 = 231072 will be the highest UID mapped to the `dockremap` user.

In [Docker terms](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), `dockremap` is the user the container will run as when you specify `--userns=dockremap`. UID 0 in the container will be UID 165536 on the system. UID 1 in the container will be 165537 etc.

Comment: So, it means that if docker does not use user namespace then UID 0 in the container will be UID 0 on the system. So, the root (uid=0) in the container is root on the system, yes?

Comment: Correct, and any other UID used in a container will map to that UID outside the container as well.

Comment: Although containers do provide some limitations so a user inside a container doesn't have access to everything a user would outside a container.

Comment: thanks. 
"Although containers do provide some limitations so a user inside a container doesn't have access to everything a user would outside a container. " How do they do it? You can refer me somewhere. I suppose that the process that is run under container has less capabilities, but it is only my suspicion

Comment: The [docker security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/) page is a good resource.

Comment: thanks for a link. But, especially it says: that "By default Docker drops all capabilities except those needed, a whitelist instead of a blacklist approach." It means that it drops some capabilities for container. I am not sure whether I understand it. What does it mean to drop capabilities for a **container**? (What is a container in that sense?)

Comment: A "container" is the main process and it's children that are in a cgroup and namespace for the container

Comment: Shouldn't the highest UID mapped to `dockremap` be 165536+65536-1 = 231071 ?

Comment: @ebk I don't believe so, but my wording needs fixing. UID's in the container start at 0. 65536 would actually be the highest UID rather than "number of uids allowed". Docker uses the phrase "and the next N integers in sequence"

Comment: @Matt I think you're right. I just found the following description in `man newuidmap`:  "_... each of the UIDs in the range [loweruid, loweruid+count] is allowed to the caller according to /etc/subuid ..._". Thank you for making it clearer

Comment: @ebk There seems to be conflicting information from manual pages. From [`man subuid`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/passwd/subuid.5.en.html), the number is “*numerical subordinate user ID count*”.

Comment: @FranklinYu After digging into the source code of package `shadow` (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/a0efca4581b3542ca4ac6311784a886272ea8481/src/newuidmap.c#L52)), I'm pretty sure that `man subuid` is correct. The range of available IDs should be [loweruid, loweruid+count). Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Just filed an [issue report of man newuidmap/newgidmap](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/issues/280) to the repository of `shadow`.

Comment: The relevant docker document about this currently is https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/