# subuid and subgid mappings not mapping the root user/group (UID/GID 0)

Tags: container

I'm getting started with running Docker 20.10.14 in [rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04). I've created a user named `dockerd` for this, UID 127 (with group `dockerd`, GID 139) and added the following to both `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`

```
dockerd:200000:65536
```

Now, inside a Docker container run by this `dockerd` user I create a file on the host file system (via a bind-mounted directory).

- If I create it as UID 1000 in the container it maps to user 200999 on the host.
- If I create it as UID 1 (user `daemon`)  in the container it has UID 200000 on the host.
- If I create it as UID 0 (user `root`)  in the container it has UID 127 on the host.

So it appears that the sub-UID/sub-GID bindings are "1-based" and do not include UID 0. Is this how it's supposed to work or am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't I be able to map the root user in the container to as UID of my choice on the host? If so, how do I do that?

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397168/107961

> ```
> dockremap:165536:65536
> ```
>
> 165536 is the system UID to start the UID mapping at (Which will be UID 0 in the container)

... it sounds like the first UID in the mapping *should* map to UID 0, but that's not what I'm seeing.

Another weird thing is that a file owner by UID 0 on the host is owned by UID 65534 (`nobody`) in the container. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Which version of Docker?

Comment: 20.10.14. Edited that in.

Comment: So is the uid of dockerd 127? in suck case it fits: 1+65536=65537 uids are mapped.

Comment: @A.B. yes, the UID of dockerd is 127, but I'm not following how "it fits" that the root user inside the container is mapped to 127 and not 200000. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Imagine *you* (rather than Docker) were to run a rootless container. Wouldn't you be happy to have the normal user be root in this container directly? That's what happens for Docker not being root on the host here.

Comment: Now I guess Docker could select a subrange inside its range to run a container with yet-an-other mapping so the container's root can't try to exploit something to reach Docker.

Comment: Well, no, I'm not happy with it. :) I would be happy if it mapped the start of the range I specified, 200000, to UID 0. Do you know how to achieve that?